# What is near the front camera on iPad Air?

Tags: ipad

I have a screen protector from Tech Armor designed specifically for the iPad Air but it covers a small, barely visible port or opening of some sort near the front camera.

I thought it was a microphone at first but upon further research, I don't think it is since the two mics are on top and back.

Is it just a light sensor perhaps and therefore doesn't matter that it's covered by a clear film?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Ambient light sensor (ALS).

> If Auto-Brightness is on, iPad adjusts the screen brightness for current light conditions using the built-in ambient light sensor.
>
> Quoted From [iPad User Guide For iOS 7 (October 2013) P.23](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1595/en_US/ipad_user_guide.pdf)

Additional information: [Quora: Where is the Ambient Light Sensor located on the iPad](http://qr.ae/G3M07)